# Is there a way to execute FME transformers from a PythonCaller script in an FME workspace?

Tags: python, fme-form, fmeobjects

I have a very large and complex Python/arcpy script that does lots of custom calculations, and I am trying to port it to an FME environemnt.  The script runs beautifully under ArcGIS.  The problem in porting is that some of the ESRI-specific functionality, especially geoprocessing tools, has to be replaced with similar FME functionality.  **So, I would like to inquire if there is a way to run FME transformers, e.g. HullReplacer, from a PythonCaller script in an FME workspace.**

True, the project could be rewritten completely in Workbench.  I have no doubt about that; however, that would take a lot of time and effort ... and to be completely honest, I am doing the port to FME for someone else who actually has the FME license.  I do not have access to FME myself.  Most of the functions of the existing script have ported almost without change to FME Workbench.  Works great.  There are a few places, though--right smack dab in the middle of the code--where some FME functionality is needed to replace some ESRI functionality, and "there's a transformer for that."  If I could execute a transformer in those places and continue processing the existing code with the output of the transformer, I could easily port the rest of the script.  I just don't know if it is possible programmatically to execute a transformer from Python.  I can't find any direct mention of this in online FME documentation or in online searches.  I have noted that a Python wrapper has been created for the IFMELibrary.  That provides a promising hint, but frankly I don't know what the IFMELibrary is or what it entails.  There is no documentation for it.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?  Thanks, all, for the help.

ADDITION:  Hmmm.  I see in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11118/how-to-use-the-transformer-kmlregionsetter-python-fme?rq=1) some sample code (in the first block) showing a transformer being called through Python.  Is this a valid and supported syntax?  If so, is there an online documentation set that covers the Python/fmeobjects syntax for calling each of the transformers?

CONCLUSION:  After a lot of searching, testing, and -- finally!-- being able to submit a question to Safe Software, my conclusion is that one cannot call FME transformers from within a Python script in a PythonCaller transformer.  This is disappointing.  I must proceed with chopping the scripts into little pieces and redoing the whole process in FME Workbench.

Comment: How are you going to test it without a license?

Comment: @blah238 trial version http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-desktop/trial-download/

Comment: for FME to access the ArcObjects components in your python code FME and ArcGIS need to be on the same computer (both licensed).

Comment: See Example http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Example-Workflow-using-FME-Python-and-Oracle

Comment: @blah238 - How do I test it?  Not very conveniently ... seriously, what I have to do is send the scripts to my boss, who has FME, and let them create the workspace.  They run it while I watch and consult over shared screens on Skype ... yes, a trial version would be good, but my boss is waiting on that until he is closer to getting me a license, too.

Comment: @Mapperz - I am not going to be using any ESRI resources in the script(s) ported to FME.  Actually, all of this is headed for FME Cloud eventually ... I will have to look some more at the example you cite above.  At first glance, I don't see any code that calls a transformer, but then I am relatively new to FME.  I might not recognize a transformer name right off the bat.

Comment: Thank you, all, for the help.  It doesn't look like there is any easy answer.  If anyone could give me some insight as to what is going on with the code in the post that I link to above in my ADDITION section, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd use only FME stuff. I'd be surprised if you can't do what you want to do with FME, though there is some stuff that you need a Desktop GIS to do it with, like Kriging. There's Hull accumulators in FME: http://blog.safe.com/2012/05/fmeevangelist105//

Comment: @alexgleith - I have been able to use some substantial chunks of the original script as is in Python Callers, but still, much dicing of the script has been required to get the same functionality within the strictly feature-centered workflow of FME.  That said, there certainly are a lot of very cool transformers!